# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python

When running my code i am using

```
for line in open(INPUT_LOGS).readlines()[:MAX_ROWS]: 
    a = parse_line(line)

if headers is None:
    header = a.keys()
```

and I am getting the above error.

Comment: you'll need to show your definition of parse_line

Comment: Is indentation correct?

Comment: Clearly `a` is `None`.

Comment: def parse_line(line):
  data = LINE_RE.match(line).groupdict()

Comment: you need to add some sort of dictionary return statement to parse line

Comment: how exactly can i do it??? I am new to python

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss on tabulation to put your if condition inside your for loop (or you just want to add `header` for the last line of your file:

```
for line in open(INPUT_LOGS).readlines()[:MAX_ROWS]: 
    a = parse_line(line)

    if headers is None:
        header = a.keys()
```

Comment: i want my key values of a to be stored in headers

Comment: For each line ? For the last line ? You should provides your `parse_line` function.

Comment: i have provided the parse_line func above in the comments